# addition query to selected item

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a listview, I already have a code that when I press the "BUY" button the Quantity left and Quantity will be subtracted in the database and will be displayed in the listview. In contrast, I want to remove a selected item and add its quantity to the quantity left. heres my code

```
 openconnection()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE products SET quantity = '" + TextBox3.Text + "' WHERE bar_code = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'", conn)

    For Each i As ListViewItem In
        ListView1.SelectedItems

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Val(TextBox5.Text) + Val(TextBox3.Text))

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", TextBox3.Text)

        ListView1.Items.Remove(i)
        ListView1.Items.Remove(i)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Next


End Sub
```

The item will be removed but it won't add in the database, I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: I think you most read about parameters in sql queries https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/

Comment: Tag the `DBMS` you are using

Comment: There are a few things problems I see here. One, the parameters.addwithvalue lines aren't really adding anything at all, since there are no paramaters in your query string. You're attempting to update the quantity column with a string when it's probably an int. You should also use a naming convention besides textbox1 etc, because they aren't even being used consistently. textbox3 and combobox1 both seem to hold barcodes according to your code, yet you use textbox3 as a value for the quantity update on one line, and you add it to some textbox5 in another line. Nothing makes sense here

Answer (score 0):

Am not a expert in `vb.net` but I think your code is prone to sql injection. It looks like you have `parameters` initialised with `TextBox` value but you are not using in query

Use the `parameter's`

```
UPDATE products SET quantity = quantity - @quantity WHERE bar_code = @barcode
```